# Java Null pointer exception in constructor call

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I apologize if this has been answered in some way somewhere else, but I'm not well enough versed in java to identify a similar problem from some other situation.

It might be tough to get all the information here, so I'll try to get the essentials in.

I'm writing a Calendar program, and when I call the constructor in the demo class:

```
        System.out.println("Enter month (1 - 12)");
    month = console.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Enter year (> 1500)");
    year = console.nextInt();

    Calendar myCalendar = new Calendar(month, year);
```

I get a null pointer exception at the line where I call the constructor.  I also get one at the first function call in the constructor itself:

```
    public Calendar(int m, int y)
{
    firstDate.setDate(m, 1, y);
    firstDayOfMonth();
}
```

The second number in the setDate method call is 1 because I'm using a date class I already wrote, and for the calendar, only the month and year are required, so I set the day to be 1.

After that, my error messages become less intelligible to me, as follows:

```
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at edu.rice.cs.drjava.model.compiler.JavacCompiler.runCommand(JavacCompiler.java:272)
```

I am using DrJava to do this, if that makes any difference.  If anyone can help me understand what's going on so I can work on fixing the issue, that would be great.  I know that there may not be enough information here to provide the actual solution, but if I understood what was going on, I might be able to figure it out with a little bit of extra research.  I understand that a null pointer exception occurs when a function is called with a parameter that hasn't been initialized, but backtracking through my code, following the method calls, I couldn't find anything that hadn't been defined anywhere.  I think that those other error messages would help me know where the null pointer is coming from.

Thanks in advance, and apologies if I've broken some rule here.

Edit1:  I am initializing firstDate as follows: `private ExtDate firstDate;'  I'll try those Print statements, maybe that will help.

Edit2:  All right, I think I've got it.  Thanks for the help.  Learning process and all that.

Comment: my first guess is `firstDate` is null

Comment: firstDate or console is null.  hard to tell from what you've posted.

Comment: How are you initializing `firstDate`?

Comment: I would add `System.out.println(firstDate);` and `System.out.println(firstDayOfMonth);` to the constructor before the first of the existing method calls.

Comment: You are declaring firstDate, but not initializing it, so it is null, causing the exception.

Comment: `private ExtDate firstDate;` don't initialize firstDate. It just declares it. You have to assign a `new ExtDate()` to it or some other isntance, depending on your class design.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[NullPointerException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html) occures, when you use `null` somewhere, where you should use an object. (For more details see the reference).

In nutshell: somewhere in your code you have a null reference instead of an object. You might didn't initialize it before, and that's why you got that exception.

Regarding to your error statement, that object is probably `firstDate`. You can check it with a `System.out.println(firstDate);` call, before the `firstDate.setDate(m, 1, y);` call. Probably it will print out `null`.

Comment: So inside the Calendar constructor, the first line should be private ExtDate firstDate = new ExtDate(); ? Or should initializing firstDate take place somewhere else besides the Calendar constructor?